# Jekyll won't load anymore after update

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I made a clean install of my computer and so reinstall Ruby and Jekyll.

And seems like a big update happened and my old project won't load anymore. Here is what I have when I do a `jekyll server`

```
[Arnaud@TARDIS ~/Sites/arnaud scroll]$ jekyll server
Configuration file: /Users/Arnaud/Sites/arnaud/_config.yml
/Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/Arnaud/Sites/arnaud/_plugins/firstPar.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:86:in `block in setup'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:85:in `each'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:85:in `setup'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:5:in `new'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:5:in `process'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/bin/jekyll:83:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:400:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:66:in `run!'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
    from /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@arnaud/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Any idea ?

EDIT :

Here is the list of gems :

```
[Arnaud@TARDIS ~/Sites/arnaud scroll]$ gem list --all

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
classifier (1.3.3)
colorator (0.1)
commander (4.1.3)
directory_watcher (1.4.1)
fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
highline (1.6.19)
io-console (0.4.2)
jekyll (1.0.2)
json (1.7.7)
kramdown (1.0.2)
liquid (2.5.0)
maruku (0.6.1)
minitest (4.3.2)
posix-spawn (0.3.6)
psych (2.0.0)
pygments.rb (0.5.0)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
safe_yaml (0.7.1)
syntax (1.0.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstall nokogiri (if installed) and redo everything. Ensure that `sudo` is not used during the installation (as your Jekyll was installed without `sudo` by `gem install jekyll`).

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: I'm on Jekyll 1.0.2. Yes, I copy the wrong one, but, `serve` give me the same error. With `sudo` I have that http://pastebin.com/W2iDLfK5

Comment: @Axiol: Could you post what gems you have? `gem list --all`

Comment: @Axiol: Will `sudo gem list --all` give you the same list?

Comment: @Axiol: Yeah, they are supposed to be different. But I don't see `nokogiri` in there, so looks right to me. Try just install nokogiri by `gem install nokogiri`. Then run jekyll again

Comment: Seems like it made it, still have these errors, but it mights comes from my custom pagination http://pastebin.com/wbzChfFy Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: @Axiol: Cool, care to accept and upvote this answer? For the custom pagination issue, I'm not so familiar with, sorry. You might want to create a new question for that, see if someone else can help out.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I'll dig into it and read the changelog for the 1.0 :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's something wrong with your setup. For example, the following error

```
/Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

shouldn't be happening in case the Jekyll gem was installed (or could at least be reached) correctly. (most of the Jekyll problems are related to lack of correct YAML front matter, to be honest)

If you pay attention to `sudo gem list --all`, you'll notice that jekyll isn't installed when you use `sudo`. Did you try:

```
gem install jekyll
jekyll serve
```

This should work, or at least give you a "better" error.

Ah, a good solution to avoid these errors (or at least control them easily) is to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) gemsets to separate your gems. It's *very* useful for debugging.