# install jekyll on linux(fedora 20)

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, jekyll, fedora20

Everyone, I used `sudo gem install jekyll` to install jekyll on my Fedora 20 and got the following error. I've successfully installed ruby and rubygems, and it seems to me the jekyll has been installed. But when I enter `jekyll serve`, the pages won't be created and I got the similar message. I'm new to fedora and ruby, thanks for any help.

```
Successfully installed jekyll-2.1.0
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- json/pure (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:60:in `rescue in <module:JSON>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:57:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/text.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/code_object.rb:28:in `<class:CodeObject>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/code_object.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/generator/markup.rb:59:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:565:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:73:in `load_rdoc'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:238:in `setup'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:151:in `generate'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:56:in `block in generation_hook'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:55:in `generation_hook'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:178:in `call'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:178:in `block in install'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:177:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:177:in `install'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:249:in `install_gem'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:291:in `block in install_gems'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:287:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:287:in `install_gems'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:202:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/command.rb:307:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
    from /bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4):

try to install `ruby-devel` by this -

```
sudo yum install ruby-devel
```

and the try to re install `jekyll` -

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

And also make sure you have `nodejs` installed,

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with your JSON parser. See `cannot load such file -- json/pure` in your stacktrace? You need to be able to successfully run `gem install json` or `gem install json_pure` before you can run Jekyll.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and installed some more required software and it worked. I still got one more question to ask, in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033621/jekyll-wont-load-anymore-after-update?rq=1), people say `sudo gem install jekyll` and `gem install jekyll` have different effects, and enter `gem list --all` with or without `sudo`, I got a whole different list of gems. Why is that?

Comment: The `sudo` prefix for the gem command gives you a global perspective on your rubygems installation. So, if you run simply `gem install` (without sudo or root permissions) you will install a particular gem locally, under your current home directory.